# Проблема с MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Вот такая вот ошибочка:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Атаман' (свинина, помидор, лук, сыр, чесн, м-з)'' at line

```
SELECT * FROM `db_price` WHERE `name`='Мясо 'Атаман' (свинина, помидор, лук, сыр, чесн, м-з)' AND `date`='20'
```

> Filename: /bhome/part2/01/dchem/domobed.ru/www/admin/controllers/admin.php Line Number: 464

Запрос такой:

```
"SELECT * FROM `db_price` WHERE `name`='".$names."' AND `date`='".$day."'"
```

Помогите решить.

Comment: Тут и решать не нужно, видите **Атаман** подсвечен, это и есть ошибка! Уберите кавычки возле этого слова! З.Ы. пора переходить на редакторы с подсветкой синтаксиса!

Comment: Кавычки убирать не надо, если я их уберу, то у меня следующие запросы не выполнятся.

Comment: Ну не убирайте... мне то чего... `syntax to use near 'Атаман'` говорит сам за себя!

Comment: убрал, теперь такая ошибка:
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'овощной с фрикадельками из мяса курицы AND `dat' at line 1

SELECT * FROM `db_price` WHERE `name`=Суп овощной с фрикадельками из мяса курицы AND `date`='20'

Filename: /bhome/part2/01/dchem/domobed.ru/www/admin/controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 464

Comment: Суп овощной с фрикадельками из мяса курицы - нужно взять в кавычки

Comment: Попробуйте почитать [мануал][1].


  [1]: http://ru.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM `db_price` WHERE `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($names)."' AND `date`='".mysql_real_escape_string($day)."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя одинарные кавычки в запросе в названии колбасы, а они являются специальным символом SQL

для вставки таких используй схему \'

пример: SELECT * FROM `db_price` WHERE `name`='Мясо \'Атаман\' (свинина, помидор, лук, сыр, чесн, м-з)' AND `date`='20'

mysql_real_escape_string сделает это за тебя

Comment: Извините, а чем ваше решение отличается от уже предложеного?